# Delete all expressions in Expression editor

Tags: python, expression, maya

In this maya scene file of mine, when scrubbing through the time slider, I keep getting the following error:

```
// Error: An execution error occured in the expression stabilizator_expression_mom_bq01_v2_original_2Shape6. //
```

Upon opening the editor, this is the full error:

```
# Error: line 0: No module named mmTools.v1_0.ford_stabilizerStereo
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
# ImportError: No module named matchmoveTools.v1_0.ford_stabilizerStereo #
```

Even so, I can delete such expressions in the Expression Editor, but it is a list of it and unfortunately, it has to be done done manually, clicking on them one-by-one for deletion. Tried the following code but no expressions seem to be deleted:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.delete( all=True, e=True )
```

As such, was wondering if anyone knows if there are any ways that I can delete all existing expressions using python at one go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According for Maya docs that should have worked but as you mentioned it does't seem to work. One option can be

```
cmds.delete(cmds.ls(type='expression'))
```

I am not sure if this is answers your question.

Comment: By the way, you are missing a closed bracket `)` in your code and I am unable to edit it